# Change the color of the button relative to the value in the textbox

Tags: c#

I'm creating an app and looping on one thing. When I type in the textbox the numbers 1, 2, 3, 50, the buttons that have these values ​​change their colors. When there is one number it is obtained, but when there are many it does not happen

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKGwP.png)

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "1")
            {
                button1.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
            }
        }
```

I say that if the value is equal to 1 then change my color, but if I have values ​​separated by commas I don't understand them.

Comment: Please post a minimal example of your code to clearly show the problem :)

Comment: It should be checked where it is run. Please enter a problem code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains("1"))
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
        }
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains("2"))
        {
            //button2.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
        }
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains("3"))
        {
            //button3.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, but when I have 10 buttons and write 10, the color changes to 1 and 10

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char delimiter = ',';
    string[] splitText = textBox1.Text.Split(delimiter);
    foreach(string item in splitText)
    {
        (item == "1") button1.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
        (item == "2") button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        (item == "3") button3.BackColor = Color.Green;
        (item == "4") button4.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

OR

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char delimiter = ',';
    string[] splitText = textBox1.Text.Split(delimiter);
    foreach(string item in splitText)
    {
        switch (item)
        {
            case "1":
               button1.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
               break;
            case "2":
               button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
               break;
            case "3":
               button3.BackColor = Color.Green;
               break;
            case "4":
               button4.BackColor = Color.Blue;
               break;
            default:

               break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a specific number to each color,
you should use [switch statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) instead of hundereds of if-statements.

Also, you should use ".Contains" instead of ".Text", so it will ignore the whole rest
and only search for the specific number.